# UPDATE mysql op not working with cc-number

Tags: php, html, mysql

I ' m trying to update user info by sending a form, but if I change credit card (tarjeta credito) field, it doesn't work, despite of the function receives the new data. If I put 000000000000 value it works, and later if I put for example 333333333333333, It always store this value: '2147483647'

```
        {
            $usuario->tarjetaCredito = 123121123123;
            var_dump($usuario->tarjetaCredito);
            $app = App::getSingleton();
            $conn = $app->conexionBd();
            $query=sprintf("UPDATE usuarios U SET nombre='%s', password='%s', nombreUsuario='%s', dni='%s', direccion='%s', email='%s', telefono='%s', ciudad='%s', `codigo postal`='%s',`tarjeta credito`=%d WHERE U.id = %d"
            , $conn->real_escape_string($usuario->nombre)  
            , $conn->real_escape_string($usuario->password)
            , $conn->real_escape_string($usuario->nombreUsuario)
            , $conn->real_escape_string($usuario->dni)
            , $conn->real_escape_string($usuario->direccion)
            , $conn->real_escape_string($usuario->email)
            , $conn->real_escape_string($usuario->telefono)
            , $conn->real_escape_string($usuario->ciudad)
            , $conn->real_escape_string($usuario->codigoPostal)
            , $usuario->tarjetaCredito
            , $usuario->id);
            if ( $conn->query($query)) {
                if ( $conn->affected_rows != 1) {
                    echo "No se ha podido actualizar el usuario: " . $usuario->nombreUsuario;
                    exit();
                }
            } else {
                echo "Error al insertar en la BD: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . utf8_encode($conn->error);
                exit();
            }
            
            return $usuario;
        }


...
     <div class="form-group m-2">
                    <label>tarjeta credito:</label> <input class="form-control" name="tarjetaCredito" value="$tarjetaCredito"  type="tel" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9\s]{13,19}"placeholder="xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx" autocomplete="cc-number" maxlength="19" />
                </div>
...

mysql table:
    `tarjeta credito` int(20) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: What is the definition on the database of that field?

Comment: your code is **vulnerable** to **sql injection** please use always **prepared statements with parameters** this also could fiy your problems

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help you get the best result on Stack Overflow, see how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback). Sometimes the same question may have already been asked. Make sure your question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A credit card number is not a "number" in the mathematical sense, it just happens to be a string of digits. You never need to ask "what is this card number plus one?" or "...times two?", but you might want to ask "what are the first four digits of this card number?" or "the last four...?"

If you do treat it as a number, it will be a number much larger than you would normally work with: 44443333322221111 (a Visa test card number) is "4 quadrillion 444 trillion 333 billion 322 million 221 thousand 1 hundred and 11".

Importantly, the largest number that can be stored in a signed 32-bit integer - which is what you get when you specify "int" in SQL - is just more than 2 billion, so a card number doesn't come close to fitting. Your database will either give you an error, or just store some other number that does fit - in your case, it's just storing the highest number it can.

You could change your column to a "bigint" (64-bit signed, maximum value around 9 quintillion), but you're better off treating them as strings in your PHP, and VarChar in your database.